# What does "the access to [...] has been premature" mean?

Tags: meaning

In one of his promotional lectures, Dr. David Berlinski says as follows:

> ... Nonetheless, I've written this book. And I've written this book
> because it seems to me that **the access to** atheism in the name of
> science (and, after all, we don't have another name we can appeal to)
> has been premature. It's been extremely vulgar, it's been historically
> illiterate, and it's made some catastrophically mistaken judgements
> about what science can or cannot do, what it has or has not done.

What does he mean by "the access to ..."?

Here's the video. The appropriate portion starts at 8:57:

https://youtu.be/vtgV2VP9iEQ?t=537

Comment: Do you have a link to the video? If this is from a transcript it could be a transcription error.

Comment: @alphabet: Just added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As MW explains,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/access) "access" can mean  "an increase by addition," giving the example "a sudden access of wealth." In this case, he is talking about the recent increasing support for and promotion of atheism. He likely has in mind works like *The God Delusion* by Richard Dawkins (2006), to which his book *The Devil's Delusion* (2008) is presumably a response.

This use of "access" is rather obscure, and using it with "to" seems unidiomatic. But it does seem to be a quirk of Berlinski's writing. From his book [*Human Nature*, p. 27:](https://www.discovery.org/m/2019/12/Human-Nature-David-Berlinski.pdf)

> Russian foreign policy was hardly a model of steadfast lucidity. Sergei Sazanov, Russia’s foreign minister, had acquired influence as Pyotr Stolypin’s brother-in-law, and in his **access to power,** he had been pushed from below as well as pulled from above

In the context of the above sentence, the usual meaning of "access" does not really fit. He seems to be using "in his access to power" to mean something like "in the addition to his power," though one could also interpret this as "an act of accessing," another definition MW cites.

Comment: Nice. You're right, "of" would have been more logical (or more idiomatic, if you will) than "to."

Comment: I suspect that he has heard the phrase "access to" so often (with the normal sense of "access") that he is now using it with a completely different sense of "access," even though the preposition "to" makes little sense in that case.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: And another thing: the dude is amazingly eloquent and well-spoken (in my opinion, he speaks a great deal better than he writes). That said, he's fluent in seven languages, and the slip may have been the result of his forming the phrase in a language other than English first. I don't know. His lectures and interviews are invariably great fun and joy. He's lived in Paris this past quarter-century or so.

Comment: He might even have in mind that the "ac-" in "access" comes from Latin "ad," meaning "to, towards."